# Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent PHPUnit / Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I have this strange problem when i call the `parent::setUp()` on my TestCase class for unit test a class
when i run phpunit it throw me this error:

> 1) MatchRequestRepositoryTest::test_find_requests_by_match_id
>   ErrorException: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /var/www/project.dev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:459)

What can be the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please check this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: You'll have to share the contents of your test. Also, is your application doing any direct manipulation of sessions, either via native `session_` function calls or `Session::`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test PHP headers with PHPunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745080/test-php-headers-with-phpunit)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(UPDATE: Thanks to comment by Louis Charette, this will only work in php 7.1 and earlier (and reading the bug report, it sounds like a regression they don't intend to fix.  The better solution is therefore Jeff Puckett's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38045422/841830), of giving the `--stderr` flag on the commandline to `phpunit`. This keeps stdout for your code, stderr for phpunit, and so they don't clash.)

---

The problem is that you have some code, perhaps deep in the framework you use, that calls `session_start()`. That, in turn, wants to send a cookie. But PHPUnit has already started writing output to stdout.

The point to understand here is that this is just a unit test, no-one cares about the header. So just suppress the error message. And the way you do that, without altering the system-under-test, is to call session_start() in your own unit test (either before `parent::setUp()` or inside that setUp function). And use the `@` prefix to suppress errors. e.g.

```
function setUp() {
  @session_start();
  parent::setUp();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will still produce an error for your test. It will produce something like this: 

`There was 1 error:
1) Classname::ClassTest
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

Comment: @w00tland The `@` should stop any errors or warnings being reported. Do you have the `@` on the line it is complaining about? And does adding/removing the `@` change the error message?  (If you cannot get the message to go away, it might be worth starting a new question; this one was about how to get rid of the "headers already sent" complaint.)

Comment: I know it should prevent warnings from being reported. The message I shared above is the result of suppressing the message. And yes, I get the `Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by` message if I remove the @. 
And I have the exact same problem; I'm just trying to get rid of the "headers already sent" message.

Comment: For people finding this though Google, this fix might produce another set of errors with PHP 7.2 in relation with `session_set_save_handler`. See : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75628
Jeff Puckett answer is a better solution in relation to PHP 7.2 change.

Comment: @LouisCharette Thanks. I've updated the answer with that info.

Answer (score 33):

One way to handle this in PHPUnit is to send output to `stderr` instead of `stdout` as is demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10815902/4233593).

```
phpunit --stderr
```

Or by adding `stderr="true"` in your phpunit.xml as is pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/39839577).

Comment: is there any backfire using this? or no problem at all? thanks

Comment: @Carlos I still haven't found any problem with it.

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but the problem i have on this solution is that it does not generate a `junit.xml` file from `phpunit.xml` for my unit test.
I guess it is because it outputs to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: @xCHAN that's an interesting caveat! I'd never thought about that side effect. You should post a solution if you discover a better option and ping me when you do.

Answer (score 4):

```
 /**
 * @test
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
public function testName(){
    //... your test
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment, explaining your answer.

Comment: @baikho this code is pretty much selfexplaining. It lets the test run in a seperate process so the headers are not already sent by phpunit.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel I avoided the issue by checking the environment and avoiding problematic code for 'testing' environment.

```
// Code working in Laravel 4.2
if(App::environment() != 'testing') {
        // this will be skipped when testing
        setcookie('key', $val, time() + (86400 * 999), '/');
}
```

NOTE - Warning: this means you cannot test this piece of code!